# Does the thread ever change once inside a reactor execution?

Tags: project-reactor

It's been hammered into my head that I shouldn't use `ThreadLocal` with Reactor. But I want to know if I can use `ThreadLocal` within a single execution of a reactor function.

Specifically, when inside a Spring Webflux Controller method, can the thread ever change if I don't invoke a reactor function?

Please let me know if this is correct

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> someControllerMethod() {
  // Thread 1 executing
  ThreadLocal<String> USER_ID = new ThreadLocal<>();
  USER_ID.set("1");

  Thread.sleep(...);

  someMethod();

  // Thread 1 executing
  assertEquals(USER_ID.get(), "1"); // this will ALWAYS be true

  return Mono.just("hello ")
    // this is the only time a new thread executes and USER_ID is not set
    .flatMap(s -> s + USER_ID.get()); 
}

void someMethod() {
  // Thread 1 executing
  assertEquals(USER_ID.get(), "1"); // this will ALWAYS be true
}
```

Is my understanding above correct?

**Revised this section for clarity**
In a reactor chain of many operators, each operator (e.g. map) could be run under different threads, and even different "instances?" (e.g. map of url N) of the same operator could be on different threads. But once we're in an instance of a operator, will it always be the same thread (ie is it safe to declare ThreadLocal in an instance of an reactor operator)?

```
// main thread
Flux.fromIterable(urls)
   .map(url -> {
      // each of these instances runs on a different thread
      // but is declaring ThreadLocal here safe to do?
      ThreadLocal<String> URL = new ThreadLocal<>();
      URL.set(url);

      // Will URL always be set deep in the call stack?
      someOtherMethod();

      // Will URL always be set at the end?
      URL.get();
   });
   .subscribeOn(Schedules.boundedElastic())
   .subscribe();

void someOtherMethod() {
  URL.get(); // will this will ALWAYS be set?
}
```

Basically, I'd like to know whether it's safe to use `ThreadLocal` objects like `io.grpc.Context` within a single instance of a Reactor operator execution.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know reactor.  But... Why?  I'd expect (I'm assuming) values in-scope within a method would remain in scope (putting aside closures, which still retain limited visibility but we know could be on diff thread).  So why would you need thread-local storage within the method?

Comment: I don't need it within the method. I need it deep in the call stack of this method but want to be sure it's available always

Comment: So your simplified example doesn't relect the reality. The real question is whether your 'call stack' does.

Comment: on Stackoverflow, we always to try to provide simplified versions of the problem. My question is trying to get at, if and when the thread ever changes. Are you suggesting that simply going down the call stack changes the thread?

Comment: @user207421 I edited my post with a call stack. Let me know if it's clearer or changes anything

Comment: thread local storage stores _copies_ of data per thread, I don't think that's quite what you want here.

Comment: @Rogue yes, I understand thread local storage associates data with its thread. I'm not sure what you mean by that second part of the statement. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What's the purpose of the data you're using in reactor here (via the `ThreadLocal` at the moment)? Should it just be safe to read/write between multiple threads, or is it unique data per-thread? Overall the only reason I would think of something not being "thread-safe" in Java is when you're using threads in the ifrst place. Perhaps Reactor models their threading differently on different machines; but overall you should be looking at _your_ problem, not reactor's. Why do _you_ need a thread local storage?

Comment: I need to use io.grpc.Context which is thread local in a React environment. So i need to understand if/when the thread changes and I lose my grpc Context. You can swap my simplified 'USER_ID.set()' with 'Context.with(...)' but I wanted to simplify the question for anyone without grpc knowledge to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's been hammered into my head that I shouldn't use ThreadLocal with Reactor.

You mustn't use ThreadLocal in a *reactive chain* with reactor (which is the only sensible way to use that library.) In a reactive chain, the thread *might* change whenever you invoke an asynchronous operator - so a single reactive chain could have operations executing on many different threads throughout. In this case your ThreadLocal might work *sometimes*, but it's unreliable - introduce an async operator that switches the thread (say a web request that's executed on the netty worker pool), and you've then introduced a subtle and weird bug that's hard to track down (you're arbitrarily leaking information from one reactive chain to another unintentionally.) In short, it's incredibly bad practice to tie your reactive chains to a single thread - while it might seem to work initially, you're going to eventually run into a lot of problems if you do.

That being said, you don't really have a reactive chain in the above method - it's *incredibly* weird. If you're returning a `Mono<String>` to try to make the method reactive, then you need to be executing everything as part of a reactive chain. What you're actually doing is:

- Using synchronous & blocking logic, a complete no-no as it ties up an event loop thread which isn't allowed;
- Calling another method that's not part of a reactive chain;
- Using a JUnit test method in a controller class;
- Wrapping up a value to return in `Mono.just()`;
- Making one `flatMap` call at the end (which won't work as it's not even mapping to a publisher to flatten, you'd have to use `map` instead.)

...so while using your ThreadLocal is *technically* "safe" in this context, from a wider perspective the implementation makes no sense at all. You realistically have two options - either make the entire method non-blocking and reactive *properly*, not just wrapping blocking logic in a reactive publisher, or make the whole controller just return a standard object and forget the reactive element entirely.

Follow-up:

> once we're in an instance of a operator, will it always be the same thread (ie is it safe to declare ThreadLocal in an instance of an reactor operator)?

No, there's at least two cases I can think of where that wouldn't be safe:

- Operators can be nested. Once you're "inside" a certain operator, there's no reason why other operators can't be used that would also switch thread.
- Code in other threads can be explicitly started even if there's no operator.

I don't *think* you can wind up in cases where the thread changes under you other than those two, but I could well be missing something, and it's still a rather delicate scenario (someone could break it quite easily.) If you *must* use a Threadlocal for some reason then I'd still be seriously considering whether you should be using reactor in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I'm trying to find the right terms to ask my question and I agree it's an incredibly weird example. I think my question is "In a reactor chain of many operators, each operator (e.g. flatMap) could be run under different threads, and even different "instances?" (e.g. flatMap of item N) of the same operator could be on different threads. But once we're in an instance of a operator, will it always be the same thread (ie is it safe to declare ThreadLocal in an instance of an reactor operator)?"

Comment: I revised my code sample. Hopefully, the question is clearer and the example is better.

Comment: I believe this answer addresses my concern. Basically, for threads to change, I (or someone else) would have to explicitly put in code (e.g. create a new reactor chain, have ExecutorService execute code) to cause the Thread change. Anything else (e..g a blocking call, going deep in a call stack) won't allow Reactor to arbitrarily substitute a new thread to continue the execution.